# splitting file and how to access certain index python

Tags: python

my code reads in python

> ```
>  openFile=open(filename,"r")
>  for lines in openFile.readlines():
>      line = lines.strip()
>      if line: 
>         tabsplit=line.split("\t")
>         print(tabsplit)
> ```
>
> > 

which yeilds this...

> ```
> ['-120.066667  35.000000    844']   
>  ['-120.050000  35.000000    916']
>  ['-120.033333  35.000000    971']
>  ['-120.016667  35.000000   1103']...
> ```

I am not understanding why when i go to print(tabsplit[2])
it says

IndexError: list index out of range

what i want is to be able to access each value, so that when i say

print(tabsplit[0]) i get all the -120.06,-120.05...

I wrote a code for a different type of file that works just fine, this is why i am confused, to why it is not working.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
tabsplit=line.split()
```

you dont actually have a tab character in your file instead you have consecutive whitespace

it mat have been a tab at somepoint... but then some editor changed it to being seperated by consecutive white space

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Joran, `line.split` is not splitting at all, you are just getting the complete line at the output.